# Entity Framework Core: Column, parameter, or variable #4: Cannot find data type bool

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor

I'm a bit confused on this issue, although it is self explanatory. I did try changing the data types from bool to bit, however, the bit data type present white in color and has a red squiggly. You'll find my code below with the data type changed to bit. Note, this is after I run the add-migration command and look at the migration code.

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "AspNetUsers",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                UserName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                NormalizedUserName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                Email = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                NormalizedEmail = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                EmailConfirmed = table.Column<bit>(nullable: false),
                PasswordHash = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                SecurityStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                PhoneNumber = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                PhoneNumberConfirmed = table.Column<bit>(nullable: false),
                TwoFactorEnabled = table.Column<bit>(nullable: false),
                LockoutEnd = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(nullable: true),
                LockoutEnabled = table.Column<bit>(nullable: false),
                AccessFailedCount = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                FirstName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                LastName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
            },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the [mapping between C# data type to SQL Server column data type](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/conventions-in-ef-core.aspx) when using Entity Framework Core.

[image]

The C# `bool` type will be mapped to the SQL Server `bit` Type. So, in the C#, we have to use the `bool` type, instead of `bit` type, but you can set the type property to `bit`. Code like this:

```
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "TestTables",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                Email = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                EmailConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                LockoutEnd = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false),
                LockoutEnabled = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_TestTables", x => x.Id);
            });
```

The SQL server database result like this:

[image]

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help and detailed explanation of the error I was receiving. I will make sure to mark this as the accepted answer. I had ran into this error before, however, I couldn't remember what the issue was. Thank you again for the clarification.